django problemas al instalar mysqlclient
Estoy intentando instalar mysqlclient en django pero al momento que escribo el comando pip install mysqlclient me sale este error (yo uso MYSQL, tuve que configura en la variables del sistema a mano ,ya que mysql server no me configuró en 'INCLUDES' Y 'LIB' en las variables del sistema a , e uso el MySQL Connector C 6.1):

(env) PS C:\proyectos\projectdj\psy> pip install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: mysqlclient
Building wheel for mysqlclient (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
× python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [42 lines of output]
running bdist_wheel
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb_init_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\connections.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\converters.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\cursors.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb
copying MySQLdb\times.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb
creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants_init_.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CLIENT.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\CR.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\ER.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FIELD_TYPE.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb\constants
copying MySQLdb\constants\FLAG.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb\constants
running build_ext
building 'MySQLdb.mysql' extension
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release
creating build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\MySQLdb
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe" /c /nologo /O2 /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Dversion_info=(2,1,1,'final',0) -D__version_=2.1.1 "-IC:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\include\mariadb" "-IC:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\include" -IC:\proyectos\projectdj\env\include -Ic:\users\javier.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.4\include -Ic:\users\javier.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.4\Include "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Auxiliary\VS\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\winrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.22621.0\cppwinrt" "-IC:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\include" /TcMySQLdb/_mysql.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj
_mysql.c
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(311): warning C4244: 'inicializando': conversi¢n de 'Py_ssize_t' a 'int'; posible p‚rdida de datos
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(943): warning C4244: 'funci¢n': conversi¢n de 'Py_ssize_t' a 'unsigned long'; posible p‚rdida de datos
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(948): warning C4244: 'funci¢n': conversi¢n de 'Py_ssize_t' a 'unsigned long'; posible p‚rdida de datos
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(1000): warning C4244: 'funci¢n': conversi¢n de 'Py_ssize_t' a 'unsigned long'; posible p‚rdida de datos
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(1005): warning C4244: 'funci¢n': conversi¢n de 'Py_ssize_t' a 'unsigned long'; posible p‚rdida de datos
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(1454): warning C4244: '=': conversi¢n de 'Py_ssize_t' a 'int'; posible p‚rdida de datos
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(1767): warning C4244: 'funci¢n': conversi¢n de 'SOCKET' a 'long'; posible p‚rdida de datos
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(1853): warning C4244: 'funci¢n': conversi¢n de 'Py_ssize_t' a 'unsigned long'; posible p‚rdida de datos
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(1877): warning C4244: 'funci¢n': conversi¢n de 'Py_ssize_t' a 'unsigned long'; posible p‚rdida de datos
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(2088): warning C4996: '_snprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _snprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(2091): warning C4996: '_snprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _snprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
MySQLdb/_mysql.c(2124): warning C4996: '_snprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using _snprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe" /nologo /INCREMENTAL:NO /LTCG /DLL /MANIFEST:EMBED,ID=2 /MANIFESTUAC:NO "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\lib\mariadb" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\MariaDB\MariaDB Connector C\lib" /LIBPATH:C:\proyectos\projectdj\env\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\javier.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.4\libs /LIBPATH:c:\users\javier.pyenv\pyenv-win\versions\3.7.4 /LIBPATH:C:\proyectos\projectdj\env\PCbuild\amd64 "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\lib\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\ucrt\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\lib\10.0.22621.0\um\x64" "/LIBPATH:C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.1\lib" kernel32.lib advapi32.lib wsock32.lib shlwapi.lib Ws2_32.lib crypt32.lib secur32.lib bcrypt.lib mariadbclient.lib /EXPORT:PyInit__mysql build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\MySQLdb/_mysql.obj /OUT:build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-37\MySQLdb_mysql.cp37-win_amd64.pyd /IMPLIB:build\temp.win-amd64-cpython-37\Release\MySQLdb_mysql.cp37-win_amd64.lib /MANIFEST
L**INK : fatal error LNK1181: no se puede abrir el archivo de entrada 'mariadbclient.lib'
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\BuildTools\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.41.34120\bin\HostX86\x64\link.exe' failed with exit code 1181**
[end of output]
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
ERROR: Failed building wheel for mysqlclient
Running setup.py clean for mysqlclient
Failed to build mysqlclient
ERROR: Could not build wheels for mysqlclient, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based project


En la documentación dice que necesitas tener el conector de mariadb instalado. Que por cierto, el error está relacionado con eso. https://pypi.org/project/mysqlclient/
